# Trying to make my parseSentence method work. It only miscalculates the points it should be alloting

Tags: java, string

My parseSentence method is supposed to take an input string and parse each individual word, giving one point for consonants and doubling the score for vowels. It needs to start at 1 point for each word and adds the scores of the individual words, not take the total overall score of all characters. It also shouldn't count spaces as characters. I am trying to make my parseSentence method process each word but it parses the first and calls it quits. It should be restarting its count at every word. Instead, it doesnt't. E.g. "as a" should be 5 points "as": 1*2(for a)+1(for s) =3 and 1*2(for the next a)=2, add them both and get 5. instead it continues from s and doubles the 3 and makes it 6.

```
import java.util.*;
public class WordGolf {
    public static int points;
    public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println("Enter word: ");
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String Input = sc.next();
       System.out.println(parseSentence(Input));
    }

public static int parseWord(String input, int start){
   String charList = "aeiouyAEIOUY";
   int tempPoints = 1;
   points = 1;
   for(int x = start; x < input.length();x++){
         if(charList.indexOf(input.charAt(x)) != -1){
            points *= 2;
         }
         else{
         points++;
         }
   System.out.println("Test");
   }

   return points;
}
   public static int parseSentence(String input){
       int startPoint = 0;
       String badList = " ";
   for(int x = 0; x < input.length();x++){
      if(badList.indexOf(input.charAt(x)) != -1){         
      startPoint = badList.indexOf(input.charAt(x)) + 1;
      parseWord(input, startPoint);
      }

   }

   return points;
 }



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the points variable in WordSolf and the points variable in parseWord.

They should be different variables. I'd rename them to make it clear, for instance totalPoints and wordPoints.